# Why the revmob ads flickering?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, revmob

I have integrated the `revmob` sdk in my application the full screen ads are shown but when i clicked the cross button the ads become flickering please any help.

Comment: Can you give more details like if are you using the native SDK? Which version? What are the difference between this project and the others?

Answer (score 1):

Well that seems to be an issue with the **RevMob ad's** servers. Sometimes from the backend this problem occurs when the data isn't coming correctly. If you have implemented the ad framework *correctly* following the tutorial they provided(Which is relatively easy to implement) then there would be no issue on your development side. You could put a question up to their forums and they'll get back to you. Hope this helps.